# Unable to access a property of an object in JavaScript - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I have an Object obj which has a property "value" with a value of 123. When I `console.log(obj)` I see firefox print the object with all its fields.

When I try to print the value of the "value" property, I get undefined.

I tried:

```
console.log(obj.value);
```

and

```
console.log(obj[value]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(obj.value);` should work (the other one wouldn't). Are you doing some Ajax stuff by any chance and log the object before it is populated (the success handler is called, see [my blog post](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/) for the issue I'm referring to)?

Comment: `console.log( "value" in obj );` will tell you if your object really has a property with that name.

Comment: Please show the object definition. The first examle looks correct if there is a property called value. The second should be obj['value'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object has got value which looks like this:

```
obj={value:"Object Value"};
```

then `obj.value` and `obj['value']` is valid.

```
 console.log (obj.value); //Output will be 'Object Value'
 console.log (obj['value']); //Again output will be same 'Object Value'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

In javascript you can use square brackets and dot notation almost interchangeably.

[More information on dot vs square bracket notations](http://modernjavascript.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/dot-vs-square-bracket-notations-in.html)

Comment: What is happening is that the call doesn't have enough time to come back before I print the value.